# Problems installing Redmine and Ruby on UbuntuVirtual Server

Tags: ruby, apache, redmine

I´m trying to get Redmine running on a Ubuntu4.18 Virtual Server. I followed "[Installation von Redmine und Git unter Ubuntu](http://raphael.kallensee.name/journal/installation-von-redmine-und-git-unter-ubuntu/)" which goes through all the needed steps. Unfortunately, Redmine, which lays under this path:

```
http://lvbs46-163-79-118.dedicated.hosteurope.de/redmine/
```

(url changed a bit because of public), isn´t doing anything. For me, it looks like Ruby is not working corretly, or connected to Apache.

What I tried is:

```
http://lvbs46-163-79-118.dedicated.hosteurope.de/redmine/info.php
```

(`phpinfo();`) which tells me that the Redmine directory is viewable (CHMOD) and further that mod_passenger is loaded as written in the tutorial.

Next, I checked Ruby with `ruby -v` in terminal which shows:

```
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-linux]
```

But if I upload a Ruby testfile with content:

```
print 'Hello World!'
```

and open it in my browser it only displays `"print 'Hello World!'"`. This is why I think Ruby isn´t working correctly and Redmine maybe also not.

I think apache2.conf should load Ruby because of these added lines:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
AddType text/html .rb .rbx

LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
```

One supplement, in the plesk panel are some checkboxes for this domain which are checked:

- X PHP support (run as  )
- X CGI support (cgi-bin directory is located in  )
- X Perl support
- X Python support
- X FastCGI support (required for Ruby on Rails)

Maybe my problem has something to do with enabled FastCGI support?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the virtual server itself. I reinstalled it and know it seems to work.